# What conditions on $B$ to obtain selfadjointness?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and let $A, B$ two operators with densely defined domains (in $H$). Suppose that $B$ is linear, closed and with no-empty resolvent set, while $A$ is linear, self-adjoint and $A\subset B$. My question is: It is true that $B$ is also self-adjoint?

Could anyone give some references about the behaviuor of selfadjoiontness when we consider the inclusion of operators?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I guess that the statement is true if the resolvent set of $A$ has some elements that are common to the resolvent of $B$. In this case $A=B$ and then also $B$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming $A^*=A$ and $A \subseteq B$. Then
$$
                   B^* \subseteq A^* = A \subseteq B.
$$
So $B^*$ is symmetric. If $B=B^*$, then $B=A$.

Comment: Why $B^{\ast}$ is symmetric?

Comment: I am looking for a condition on $B$ to be self-adjoint, so I can’t suppose $B = B^{\ast}$.

Comment: @C.Bishop : That follows. If $B=B^*$ then $B=A$. Conversely, if $B=A$, then $B=B^*$ because $A=A^*$.